# Dynamic binding of ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

When a user takes a certain action, I insert a link into the text of a contenteditable field:

```
var newElement = document.createElement('span');
newElement.innerHTML = "<a id='123' class='cite' href='' data-ng-click='review(123);'>[&#8225;]</span>";
range.insertNode(newElement);
$compile($(newElement).contents())($scope);
```

When the user clicks onthe new field, I want to execute the review method of the activate controller.  ($scope.review = function(id) {...};)

Instead the page navigates to '#', without calling review();

I am assuing the click method doesn't get 'bound' to $scope.review() by a call to range.insertNode(newElement); ?  I tried wrapping in an $apply, but that didn't work.

Comment: Try replacing # with javascript:void(0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to preventDefault on anchor tags in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags-in-angularjs)

Comment: I am not concerned with how to stop default behavior, the issue is how to get it to execute the review() method defined in the controller when the element (and thus ng-click) have been added 'on the fly'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `href=""` instead of `href="#"` with Angular. The default action is always prevented if the href is empty. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:a

Also make sure to [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) that element. Ideally this would be a case for [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) if what you're doing is essentially making a list of elements.

Comment: OK, changed the href="" and added a compile step (editted above) but still no click action

Comment: Oh and ng-repeat is not a factor, as these elements are sparse, and not repeated (I'm adding a span to indicate a footnote in a editable DIV)

Comment: Have you tried just `$compile($(newElement))($scope);`, without the `.contents()`? `$compile(newElement)($scope);` might be enough as well.

Comment: OK, that did work, I just had the wrong scope.  $compile($(newElement).contents())($scope); was what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the code of your template, you can remove the href attribute altogether. If you want it to navigate, include that in the ng-click expression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an href tag at all in the  element for ng-click to work. If you want the pointer to change on hover, you can use an inline style or css.