# Does Angular interfere with this click event binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created an angular-based mobile application and I do most click event binding via ng-click in the DOM. Unfortunately I had to use some jQuery because I needed to inject a new DOM element and then bind a click event to that:

```
$('<a href="">').on('click', function () {
    alert('ok');
}).text('hello').appendTo($el);
```

For some reason this event never gets called though. Does Angular prevent this?

---

**Update:** I tried using $compile but that didn't help either:

```
var newDirective = angular.element("<a href='' ng-click='onLinkClicked()'>test</a>");
$el.append(newDirective);
$compile(newDirective)($scope);
```

And also:

```
$scope.onLinkClicked = function () {
  alert("ok");
};
```

Comment: You could try using `document.addEventListener()` if you are having problems using Jquery on this case.

Comment: There are techniques to insert elements dynamically in an Angular way

Comment: Never ever use Jquery with angular! Angular has a light version Jqlite. And you should inject something using the view / template / directive not manipulatinh the DOM directly.

Comment: can you provide a bit more code how you use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic binding of ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364208/dynamic-binding-of-ng-click)

Comment: @BrunoHenrique Nope, `document.addEventListener()` didn't help

Comment: @KirillSlatin What techniques? Can you explain?

Comment: @zhywu I saw that and replace `href="#"` with `href=""` but that didn't help

Comment: @Grundy What code exactly would you like to see?

Comment: That's weird, could your provide more code ?

Comment: did you do something similar to $compile($(newElement).contents())($scope)?

Comment: It's basically `ng-if` for a fixed number of directives or `$compile` for variable number. The latter being rather low level as you define the scope for the element. I guess it's covered enough in question mentioned by @zhywu

Comment: @zhywu See my updated answer, $compile didn't help

Comment: @BrunoHenrique What exactly would you like to see?

Comment: Don't need more code, you already explained what I wanted to know. If you want to trigger a function when your `<a>` element is clicked, isn't using `<a ng-click='yourFunction()...' an option ?

Comment: The weird thing is that document.addEventListener should have worked. Could you post how you used it ?

Comment: @BrunoHenrique I tried using ng-click but that didn't work either :(

Comment: @BrunoHenrique I used it like this: `$el.get(0).addEventListener('click', function () { alert('hello') });`

Comment: Could you `console.log($el.get(0))` to see if the element is the one your really want to bind the click event ?

Comment: @BrunoHenrique Nah, I give up and completely remove jQuery and rewrite everything the Angular way. Thanks for your help tho.

Comment: what is `$el`? where you call this code?

Comment: can you provide sample plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few days later I finally figured out what the problem was. I am the biggest idiot in the world. A few lines below the event binding I found this:

```
$scope.el = $el.html();
$scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function () {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.el);
};
```

Of course, converting the jQuery object to a plain HTML string will cause it to loose all bound event listeners because the conversion from text to DOM element will create a new node but not copy the attached event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

This happens most of the time because your jQuery section may run sooner than Angular finished its stuff and it tries to bind the *click* to a non existent element, it's not Angular preventing it.

You can test this by encapsulating the jQuery binding in a `$timeout`.

If this is the case you may want to wait for your page/directive to compile the newly added element and only then run the jQuery binding.

By the way, this is not the proper way to manipulate the DOM when using Angular. Most of the time you can bypass jQuery by using directives.

Comment: Your timeout should be called *after* you have added the element otherwise it's useless. Then, you can try increasing the time to a ridiculous  value and see if the element is bound to the click event. I guess you looked into the DOM to see that your element actually exists after you insert it? :)

Comment: If I can click it, I guess it exists :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you formulated it, you want to click on a specific `<a href="">` element but Jquery does not know this expression as a valid CSS selector.

I would not suggest to use Jquery combined with Angular. I should make use of the compile function within directives, but the JQuery code below will create an `<a>`
element:

```
$('<a href="">').appendTo('body').text('hello').appendTo($el);
```

Comment: I'm not selecting an element here, instead I create a new node

Comment: But still: Jquery works with CSS Selectors and `<a href=""'>` is not a valid css selector. As far as I can see in your question you bind a click event on the element. Using `'a'` as selector also works I think if you don't have an id on the element. Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZDNsFlOkmseZSnhErnbz?p=preview

Comment: @ABr, code in OP not _select_ something, it **create** new `a` tag: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

Comment: I updated my code to let it create a new <a> element.

Answer (score 0):

A working example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.directive("myControl", function($compile){
            return{
                template: "<button ng-click='createNewLink()' >create new link</button>",
                controller: function($scope, $element){
                    $scope.createNewLink = function(){
                        var buttonElement = $("<a href='' ng-click='newLinkClick()'>jquery created new link</a>");
                        var newLink = $compile(buttonElement[0])($scope);
                        $element[0].appendChild(newLink[0]);

                        newLink = $compile("<a href='' ng-click='newLinkClick()'>angular created new link</a>")($scope);
                        $element[0].appendChild(newLink[0]);
                    };
                    $scope.newLinkClick = function(){
                        alert("new link clicked");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div my-control></div>
</body>
```