# angularjs routing conflict with jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-routing

I'm having a problem with angular routing mechanism:

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/", { templateUrl: "/*some MVC calls to return a partial view*/"})
  .when("/somewhere/:someParams", { templateUrl: "/*some MVC calls to return a partial view*/"})
  ...
  .otherwise({redirectTo: "/"})
```

The problem is I'm using a [wrapbootstrap](https://wrapbootstrap.com/)'s theme (more accurately the [Ace](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ace-responsive-admin-template-WB0B30DGR)) and it has  lots of functionality based on `<a>` tags and `href="#"` attributes and whenever the user clicks an element (like the dropdown menus which also have a `<a href="#">` tag), angularjs jumps in and tries to parse the url which looks like this most of the time: `http://localhost/site/somewhere/someParams#`

any suggestions on how to separate these two functionality?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags-in-angularjs). The approach is to have a directive that will prevent the default action (in your case, navigating to "/#").

You can modify the directive to navigate only when the location is not "/#". Using the `attrs` parameter in the function (see the accepted answer for the above question) identify the value of the `href` attribute. Based on its value you can then chose to proceed normally or to prevent the browser from navigating to the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You may chech my question's answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found my answer today while reading `AngularJS`'s docs. the `<a>` tag is already a directive in angular and it's written so that when given an empty `href` (`<a href="">`) it prevents the default behavior of the a tag