# set value from model to view on click eventhandler

Tags: angularjs

Im a new angularJS developer. Trying to learn the basics. Im following some examples in a book, but are having problems getting this code to work.

In my controller:

```
   $scope.myGroups = [
     {Name:'MiaFamilia',Members:'13',newMessages:'1'},
     {Name:'Party newyears 13',Members:'23',newMessages:'12'},
     {Name:'My work group',Members:'3',newMessages:'5'}
   ];

   $scope.setGroup = function(row) {        
     window.alert(row);
     $scope.theValue = row; 
   }
```

Part of my view:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a ng-repeat="group in myGroups | filter:query" ng-click="setGroup($index)" 
  ng-class='{active: $index==theValue}' href="#" class="list-group-item">{{group.Name}} <span class="badge">{{group.newMessages}}</span>
  </a>
</div>
  {{theValue}}
```

The data are being rendered as expected. The `window.alert()` function are working with index, but the `{{theValue}}` are not being set.

I looked at the model also by using the angularJS tools for chrome, but the value of `theValue` are `null`.

Comment: as a side note: use `$window` instead `window`

Comment: For me its working: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/934/. What angular version do you use?

Comment: Im using 1.2.7. This is strange. But then at least it´s not a simple obvious thing I´m missing

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. If I removed the href="#" then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another element (li or p or span) instead of the link (a) tag. It shows correct value on alert because it was able to execute that script, but after that, it calls another get request reloading that page.

Or if you really need the a tag, you can try 'preventing' the default behavior. See [How to preventDefault on anchor tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags-in-angularjs)