# ng-click calling main controller not sure why

Tags: angularjs

just starting my first angularjs app

i have a snippet of html that gets loaded from the router. inside that html that gets loaded i have

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">
  <li><a  ng-click="selectFilter('hospital')" id="hospital" href="#">Hospital</a></li>
  <li><a  ng-click="selectFilter('infusion')" id="infusion" href="#">Infusion Clinic</a></li>
  <li><a  ng-click="selectFilter('ambulatory')" id="ambulatory" href="#">Ambulatory Clinics</a></li>
</ul>
```

my controller looks like

```
drugformControllers.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(URLsArray['alertsURL'][URLmode]+"5.json").success(function(data) {
        $scope.alerts = data.drugmaster;
    });
    $http.get( URLsArray['groupsURL'][URLmode] ).success(function(data) {
        $scope.pdfgroups = data.pdfgroup;
    });
    $scope.selectFilter = function() {
        console.log("filter selected");
    }
}]);
```

When one of these links a clicked, i see

```
console.log("filter selected");
```

but the ajax calls get called again, and i am unsure why

thanks for any help for this newbie

Comment: angularjs call functions twice everytimes, you have to map those urls in $resource and resolve at $routeProvider.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to preventDefault on anchor tags in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags-in-angularjs)

Comment: nemsv thanks that link had the answer, i just had to remove the href from the tag