# Angularjs ng-disable not working for anchor tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to disable a icon using angularjs in a ngrepeat scenarion. I am checking if owner is null then disbale icon. In my case icon is never disabled.

I tried printing {{item.owner == null}} which result in true.

what may be the issue and why is the icon not disabling?

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
<td style="color: gray;" title="chat">                    
<a ng-href="sip:{{item.Email}}"  ng-disabled="{{item.owner == null}}">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
</a>
</td>
```

Comment: I think this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/32085169/541432

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot apply disabled on an anchor tag, but you can make it through styling. [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) is commonly used over form controls.