# AngularJS - handle ngInclude content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have got a question about ngInclude and the handling the content included by this directive.

My situation is following code:
I have got

```
<div ng-include="route" ng-controller="SomeCtrl"></div>
```

and

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/asdf/asdf/sd.html"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Everything is included as I want to, but I am not able to realize my intention to add a `event.preventDefault();` for all the links that are included through ngInclude.

I thought I could simply do this

```
.controller('WindowContentCtrl', function($element){
    console.log($element);
    $('a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(this.href);
    });
})
```

but the result of this is that for every link except the included one throws an alert.

Any ideas how I can realise that only the `<a href="/asdf/asdf/sd.html">` throws the alert? As the route and its content is created dynamically there is no chance to add a controller in it.

Comment: You do not do DOM manipulation or binding inside Controllers, that's not what they are for. You use directives for that as they will expose and return the element in the link method. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: but that means that I have to create a new directive for every type of button or link I have in my app?

Comment: No if you just want to bind `click` on stuff then Angular as a directive for that already `ng-click`. And if you want to do some DOM manipulation for the all page you could have a single custom directive on the body tag for example and do your stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags-in-angularjs) helps you. It looks like you can augment the behavior by adding a directive on the 'a' tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using jQuery in your app.

You could bind a click event on the element that have `ng-include` with a selector like this:

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function ($element) {
  $element.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert(this.href);
  });
});
```

This should work with any `<a>` tags inside `$element` regardless of whether it is already exists in the DOM by the time the controller is initialized or not.

Or if you feel it is not right to do this in a controller, you could write a custom directive:

```
.directive('preventClicking', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        alert(this.href);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

then use it like this:

```
<div ng-include="route" ng-controller="SomeCtrl" prevent-clicking></div>
```

Hope this helps.