# Prevent page refreshing after clicking a selector, but be able to run scripts

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

I would like to ask. I have an element

```
<a href='...' data-href='...'>
```

The problem is to prevent page redirecting after clicking this element, but still be able to run JavaScript functions by onClick action.
I was trying to set

```
pointer-events: none;
```

in my CSS, but this is blocking my elements from onClick action.

Has anybody any idea how to slove that problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preventDefault on anchor tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand, you would like to prevent the link from following the url.

If this is the case you could give it an id

```
    <a id="myLink" href="...">...</a>
```

and then control the event using javascript

```
    <script>
            document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click",function(event){
                 event.preventDefault();
                 /* your code here */
            });
    </script>
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: that's it ! Thanks guys for quick answer! <3

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault()` function as the name suggests does exactly what you're looking for. Here is a good explanation of what the function does -- [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

You can use it by either of the methods shown below :-

**In JS file**

```
elem.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**In HTML itself**

```
<a href='...' data-href='...' onclick='$event.preventDefault()'>
```