# AngularJS, stop the a href?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularJS. I want to realize that type the `oneDiv` button, hide the  `oneDiv.' Then, I look the Google every time. I don't want to go the Google.  How to stop the "a href"?

The Question named "How to preventDefault on anchor tags?" is a good question.  In this question, I use the angularJs,  it is a new question due to I use the Angularjs.

```
 <style>
        .content {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .one {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .two {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

    </style>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <div class="content">
            <div ng-show="!oneHide" class="one">
                <a  href="http://www.google.com">
                    <button ng-click="oneClickFun()">XXXX</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        <div class="two">
            <a href="www.google.com">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
         var app = angular.module('app',[]);

        app.controller('controller',['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.oneHide = false;

            $scope.oneClickFun = function () {
              $scope.oneHide = true;
            }
        }])
    </script>
</body>
```

Who can modify my code to hide the `oneDiv` only?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach $event to the **oneClickFun()** called function and add **preventDefault()** in the controller function.

Try this:

```
 <style>
        .content {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .one {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .two {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

    </style>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <div class="content">
            <div ng-show="!oneHide" class="one">
                <a  href="http://www.google.com">
                    <button ng-click="oneClickFun($event)">XXXX</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        <div class="two">
            <a href="www.google.com">
            </a>
        </div>
  </div>
  <script>
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);

        app.controller('controller',['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.oneHide = false;

            $scope.oneClickFun = function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $scope.oneHide = true;
            }
        }])
  </script>
</body>
```

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<a>` element entirely. You have a `<button>`.

A `<button>` is a perfectly good UI control (it has all the affordances needed to allow users to identify it as something they can click on, and to access it to click on it even when the user depends on assistive technology).

HTML forbids `<button>` elements from appearing inside `<a>` elements.

Comment: This is my demo. In my project, the  `<a>` is the big  element,  a `button` in the `<a>` elements.

Comment: @jiexishede — HTML forbids that construct. Don't do that.

Comment: @Quentin---a `display:block` element can't  include the  `display:inline` element?

Comment: @jiexishede — An `<a>` can't include a `<button>`. [Content model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). The CSS applied to the elements is irrelevant.

Comment: I see,  <a> can include  <div> <lable> <img>  desendant, but can't include interactive content desendant.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent browser default behavior on your link:

```
$scope.oneClickFun = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent button default behavior
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevent propagation of your event to the link

    $scope.oneHide = true;
}
```

But not sure that's a best practice to put a button in a link. I assume this is just for the example? :)