# Checkbox inside anchor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have the following code:

```
   <a href class="dropdown-toggle">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test.checked">
       <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
   </a>
```

I would like to have checkbox show the checked mark when the above is clicked. Right now, clicking the link would only show the dropdown and not check the box.

I tried using $event.stopPropagation() :

```
   <input type="checkbox" ng-click="testProp($event)" ng-model="test.checked">

   $scope.testProp = function($event){
      $event.stopPropagation();
   }
```

on the checkbox, but that leaves out the anchor tag and I would only have the checkbox checked and the dropdown not shown.

Is there an angular specific for this solution. Most of the other solutions are geared towards jquery.

Comment: [How to preventDefault on anchor tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
<a href class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="checked = !checked">
   <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: you didn't give any explanation; also as @pro mentioned it doesn't work because there is no such `object` in `scope` as `test`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I've edited my answer. Basically, you just toggle `checked` value on click on `a`, and bind the checked status of checkbox to `checked`

Comment: something weird though! it only works when you click on the the angle-down and not the actual checkbox itself. sorry man, i am going to have to take back.

Comment: How about moving the checkbox outside the `a`? 
[https://plnkr.co/edit/3C8TbdYeqTtVhesqbpz6?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/3C8TbdYeqTtVhesqbpz6?p=preview)