# ng click inside li <a> element not working inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my html I have something like this :

```
   <div class="list-table-wrapper embedded-medium">
                <table class="list-table embedded-list-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <a href="#list-table" class="table-sort table-sort-desc">
                                    <span class="table-sort-text">Account Name</span>
                                    <span class="table-sort-indicator"></span>
                                </a>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <a href="#list-table" class="table-sort table-sort-desc">
                                    <span class="table-sort-text">Service Level</span>

                                </a>
                            </th>

                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items | limitTo : vm.pageSize : (vm.currentPage-1)*vm.pageSize">
                            <td class="table-link"><a ng-link="['MigrationStatus']" class="ng-binding" href="migration-status.html">{{item.accountName}}</a></td>
                            <td class="table-text">{{item.serviceLevel}}</td>
                            <td class="table-input">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <div class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="batch.showSettings = !batch.showSettings"></div>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu visible" ng-show="batch.showSettings">
                                            <li><span class="dropdown-category">Manage</span></li>
                                            <li class=""><a href="#" ng-click="removeAccount(item.accountName)">Remove from Panel</a></li>
                                            <li class=""><a href="#">View in Encore</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Now in my component I am simply console logging the same:

```
            vm.removeAccount = function(accountName){
                console.log(accountName);
            }
```

But it is simply redirecting to `localhost:8000/#` but not logging anything in console.

**UPDATE**
If I remove `href="#"` though it is not redirecting, it is not logging the data also.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags

Comment: @ThomasLangston there were couple of issue, one you mentioned & other one is related controller alias.. So can't directly mark it as duplicate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `href="#"` from the anchor tags, which is redirecting to `/#` route. I guess you haven't configured for `.otherwise` state/route that's why you can't see any changes on UI.

You could make it as `href=""` that will not perform any redirection.

And then `removeAccount` method should have `controllerAlias` before it

```
ng-click="vm.removeAccount(item.accountName)"
```

Comment: I tried that . Though it is not redirecting , it is not logging anything also.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder try updated, you had missed controllerAlias before your method name..

Comment: Such a silly mistake. Thanks for the prompt answer and pointing out the error.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder no worries, developer do it frequently, even me :P Thanks :) Glad to help you :)