# Opening a Static webpage in a new tab using Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing

I have an application and I need to open a Help page(static html) in a new browser tab.This is how I call the page

```
<a href=" " (click)="Help()"> Help </a>

Help() {
  window.open('./Help.htm','_blank','status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,location=1');
}
```

But every time I do click on help, a new window opens, and my URL in the new tab is http://localhost:4200/Help.htm#/ and my entire application is reloading there.

I just want the Static HTML to be shown in the new window.
How do I do this ?

Comment: remove `,'status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,location=1'` to just get a new tab; use preventDefault() to not reload the app - alternatively remove the href and add a pointer in css

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

Just add .htm file to assets folder and open a new window using,

`window.open('assets/popup.htm', '', 'width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200');`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the link tag to open the static link rather than doing it in a function.

The relative link in your code could also be causing issues.

Try using this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<full-path-to>/help.html">Help</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a relative path link to open a new tab.

Your function should look like this:

```
Help() {
  window.open('yourdomain.com/Help.htm','_blank','status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,location=1');
}
```